# Odoo programatically add taxes to purchase order in python

Tags: python, odoo, tax

I am creating purchase orders from an external source (online xml request).
While I loop over every order I create a purchase order, then I loop over the products and create an orderline for each product.

All of this is working except for adding taxes. I am puzzled on how to add the taxes. Should I add the values immediately to the purchase order like this ->

```
# Create orderline foreach product (this happens in the loop foreach product)
orderlineList =  {
                'name': itemText,
                'product_id': itemId,
                'product_qty': itemOrdered,
                'product_uom': 1,
                'price_unit': itemPrice,
                'date_planned': orderDatePlanned,
            }

            struct = orderlinetuple + (orderlineList,)
            po_vals.append(struct)

 #This adds all the orderlines into 'order_line'
  orderDict = { 
         'amount_untaxed' : totalNet,
         'amount_tax': totalTax,
         'partner_id': api_partner,
         'amount_total' : totalBrut,
         'order_line': po_vals,
     }
# Then we create the purchase order with the added orderlines in one go
  self.PurchaseOrder = self.env['purchase.order']   
  po_id = self.PurchaseOrder.create(orderDict)
```

If i create my purchase orders like this the amount_tax and amount_total are ignored I just get the totals from the orderlines without taxes.

Is this the wrong way? I have read about calling onchange on the purchase order but I am unsure how this works since I don't see how that will add taxes

this picture show orderlines has no taxes 
[image]

This picture show the order has no taxes
[image]

In short, how to add taxes (f.e. 21%) to a purchase order when created from the backend in python.

Kudos to the person who can point me in the right direction, been trying to find this for the last 3 days...

Comment: Depending on where you are from, taxes are difficult. F.e. germany has 7% and 19% depending on the type of goods you buy, USA have taxes that are applied on a state/region basis and may vary depending on wherefrom/whereto you ship - this may vary even from city to city or street to street. Also some of them are added taxed. Did you check all that or does it not apply to your situation? 21% sounds like austria to me. For germany for certain legal bodies do not need to pay the tax at all, because they have a tax-deductable status,

Comment: I know exactly what taxes need to be calculated, that is not the issue (21% taxes need to be added to the products) The issue is that I dont know how to do it from python when adding orders & orderlines programmatically. As in not from the web gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to call default on-change method of odoo.**

> When you call on-change method then system will automatic set tax
>   based on product default tax and purchase order fiscal position.

**Step 1:** You need to create purchase order without adding any order lines

self.env['purchase.order'].create({'partner_id':'',...})

**Step 2:** Create all purchase order line using following method.

```
    new_record=self.env['purchase.order.line'].new({'order_id':purchase_order.id,
              'product_id':product_id,
              'product_uom':uom+id,
              'name':product_name
              })

    new_record.onchange_product_id()
    order_vals=new_record._convert_to_write({name: new_record[name] for name in new_record._cache}) 
    order_vals.update({'product_qty':product_qty,'price_unit':price_unit})
    self.env['purchase.order.line'].create(order_vals)
```

In **step-2** we have create purchase order line and call onchange_product_id method. It will automatically calculate tax based on purchase order fiscal position and product default tax.

This may help you.

Comment: That makes alot of sense, thanks for explaining in depth!! Just one more question you say calculate tax based on purchase order fiscal position. Where can i set / find that??